# Datagridview check box checked is not working

Tags: c#, datagridview

I added checkbox in datagridview and trying to put default value as checked but it is showing checkbox unchecked, here is my code:

```
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(qry, myConnection);
OracleCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkColumn.Name = "X";
checkColumn.HeaderText = "X";
checkColumn.Width = 50;
checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;

dgv.Columns.Insert(8, checkColumn);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[dgv.Columns.Count - 1];
   chk.Value = chk.TrueValue;
}
```

I tried the following code also but still not showing as "CHECKED":

```
chk.Value = true;
```

Please help me solve this issue, thanks

Answer (score 1):

default value of `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.TrueValue` is `null`. Set the TrueValue property of the owning column:

```
checkColumn.TrueValue = true;
```

Comment: I tried your code but that value still null, it does not show as "CHECKED"

Comment: @imsome1, where do you invoke this code? in Form constructor or in some event handler?

Comment: From form load I am calling a function to fill data in datagridview

Comment: @imsome1, when I call try from Load method checkboxes are checked. just to be sure, is column index correct? try access by name : `row.Cells[dgv.Columns.Count - 1]` -> `row.Cells["X"]`. Also check Output window - Form doesn't throw exceptions if they are in Load method, but they are printed in Output